# How to find rows of data.frame that matches a vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching

```
pattern <- c("apple", "banana")
dat <- data.frame(fruit1 = c("melon", "apple", "mango", "apple"),
                  fruit2 = c("banana", "melon", "papaya", "banana"))

> dat
  fruit1 fruit2
1  melon banana
2  apple  melon
3  mango papaya
4  apple banana
```

I want to find out if there's a match between `pattern` and the rows in `dat`. In the example above, there is a match in the 4th row of `dat`.

I tried using `match`, but that does not seem to work on data.frames. An alternative is to loop over each row of `dat`:

```
output <- vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  output[i] <- all(dat[i, ] %in% pattern)
}
> which(output)
[1] 4
```

This is inefficient if there are many rows in `dat`. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Is this always corresponding to the columns, then `dat %>% filter(fruit1 == pattern[1] & fruit2 == pattern[2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the data like

```r
dat |>
  subset(fruit1 == pattern[1] & fruit2 == pattern[2])

#   fruit1 fruit2
# 4  apple banana
```

If you just want the index:

```r
which(colSums(t(dat) == pattern) == 2)
# [1] 4
```

or shorter

```r
which(!colSums(t(dat) != pattern))
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Approach 1: "manual" approach with indexing

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  filter(fruit1 == pattern[1] & fruit2 == pattern[2])
#>   fruit1 fruit2
#> 1  apple banana
```

## Approach 2: create a unique key across both data sources, then match with %in%.

This can be especially useful if you want to retain the "ID" that you matched on for future operations. You can remove it at the end with `%>% select(-id)` however.

```r
ids <- paste0(pattern, collapse = "")

dat %>%
  mutate(id = paste0(fruit1, fruit2)) %>%
  filter(id %in% ids)
#>   fruit1 fruit2          id
#> 1  apple banana applebanana
```

Comment: Your first approach is already in the answers

Comment: It wasn't while I was typing.